# Beginner C, why is a bunch of random stuff added to my string?

Tags: c, string

I have the following program that I want to read in my name (Sahand) character by character and store in a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char temp;
    char str[6];
    int i;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++ )
    {
        scanf(" %c",&temp);
        printf("Our temp is: %c\n",temp);
        str[i] = temp;
        printf("Our total string is: %s\n",str);
    }
    printf("Program ended with the string: %s\n",str);

    return 0;

}
```

The output is this:

```
s
Our temp is: s
Our total string is: s
a
Our temp is: a
Our total string is: sa
h
Our temp is: h
Our total string is: sah
a
Our temp is: a
Our total string is: saha
n
Our temp is: n
Our total string is: sahan
d
Our temp is: d
Our total string is: sahandd\350\367\277_\377
Program ended with the string: sahandd\350\367\277_\377
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

As you can see, everything is going fine until the final letter, d, is entered, when another d and a bunch of random stuff is added onto the string. Could someone explain to me what is happening here?

Comment: What you create is not a string. In C, a string ends with a `0` byte. Something not ending with a `0` byte is not a string, passing it to functions expecting a string is *undefined behavior*

Comment: `printf("Our total string is: %s\n",str);` will print up to str s nul terminator, and if that doesn't exist, well undefined behaviour sadness will occur. If you only allocate six characters and use all the space, no room is left for the nul terminator.

Comment: Quick fix: `char str[6] = { 0 };`

Comment: @DavidBowling not a fix if you overwrite *all* 6 characters.

Comment: @DavidBowling Not quite. Perhaps `char str[7] = { 0 };`

Comment: @FelixPalmen-- you are right; did not notice that `i` goes all the way to 5.... This may illustrate why it seems best to explicitly add the `\0` in most cases.

Answer (score 7):

You should be adding the null character to the string before printing. Since you're printing inside a loop, add it to the next character. Just absolutely be sure that the for loop doesn't go beyond the bounds of the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

char temp;
char str[7];
int i;
for ( i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++ )
{
    scanf(" %c",&temp);
    printf("Our temp is: %c\n",temp);
    str[i] = temp;
    str[i+1] = '\0';
    printf("Our total string is: %s\n",str);
}

printf("Program ended with the string: %s\n",str);

return 0;

}
```

Another option is to actually initialize each character in the C-String to be the '\0' character (without ever overwriting the last one); As some others have mentioned in the comments, this can be accomplished in the declaration of the array as such:

```
char str[7] = { 0 };
```

Comment: A minor improvement that makes code more clear and easier to maintain would be to avoid magic numbers, and do something like: `#define STR_SZ  7;`, with `char str[STR_SZ];` and `for ( i = 0 ; i < STR_SZ-1 ; i++ ) {}`.

Comment: @DavidBowling I agree. Although, since the OP said they are a newer C programmer I meant to keep the example short and concise and without syntax that they may be unfamiliar with. However, constants and other techniques can absolutely keep the code more maintainable when working on a larger file or with other programmers.

Comment: IMO that define would be poor; better would be to use `sizeof str` where required to get the array size

Answer (score 0):

You need null character(`'\0'`) to end your string(array) at the `5th` index in order to tell the compiler that this is the end of string(in your case character array i.e., `str`). But you were using `5th` index to store character `'d'`.
The compiler is taking `garbage value` from the `memory`

In order to run your program correctly, you need to declare the `str` array as below:

```
char str[7];
```

And insert null character(`'\0'`) at `(i+1)th` position.Look below:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char temp;
    char str[7];
    int i;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++ )
    {
        scanf(" %c",&temp);
        printf("Our temp is: %c\n",temp);
        str[i] = temp;
        str[i+1] = '\0';
        printf("Our total string is: %s\n",str);
    }
    printf("Program ended with the string: %s\n",str);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The OP is printing the value of the C-String inside of a loop. Thus, the null character needs to be added before each call to printf. Inserting at the 6th index only fixes the issue on the last print.

Comment: As comments and other answers indicate, this is not correct. The string is printed on every loop iteration, so the null terminator needs to be placed after the last character each time (or the appropriately sized array needs to be zero-initialized).

Comment: Yes you both `@CaitLAN Jenner` and `@David Bowling` are right. Thanks for the correction. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score -2):

After reading the comments, I changed the following line in my program:

```
char str[6];
```

to

```
char str[7];
```

That did the trick and the program executes as I wish.

EDIT:

In addition to changing this line, I added a `str[6] = 0;` after the variable declaration.

Comment: No no no. That is not a fix.  That's an uninitialised variable that can contain any random values. It may appear to work but is a time bomb waiting to fail.

Comment: So how do I end with a null byte?

Comment: You need to add a null character at the end.

Comment: Still undefined. If it "works for you", it's by accident because you're "lucky" to have a `0` at `str[6]`. Do an explicit `str[6] = 0` to terminate your string.

Comment: `char str[7] = {0};`

Comment: (or initialize like @kaylum comments, this will set ALL elements to `0` before you begin)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Easy to miss, but `str[6] = 0` will not work as OP is printing the string each iteration of the loop.